# data source name not found and no default driver specified. Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers

Tags: sql-server-2005, vba, vbscript, esxi

i'm not a windows administrator, so I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

I have this script to get vmware esxi3.5 reports,

```
http://paste.ubuntu.com/493213/
```

I get this error:

C:\Documents and Settings\admmarc\Desktop\test\vcreport.
 DB Provider for ODBC Drivers: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
 not found and no default driver specified

:\Documents and Settings\admmarc\Desktop\test>

Does anyone see what am I doing wrong?

Many thanks .

Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306345, reasons given include:

- The Microsoft Windows NT 4.0 or Windows 2000 user account that is used to process the request for the ASP page does not have sufficient permissions to read the registry key that stores the specified DSN's configuration information.
- The System ODBC DSN that is specified in the ADO connection string does not exist [on the IIS server].

Your DSN from the script is:

```
DSN=FBMVMC01\SQLEXP_VIM;UID=FBM\admmarc;PWD=password"
```

Which looks mildly suspicious, see http://www.connectionstrings.com/dsn

Comment: Thanks man.                                                       Const connStr = "DSN=VMware VirtualCenter;UID=admmarc;PWD=password"  The answer was on regedit as your first link indicates.